# how to draw multiple squares on a picture using a list of values?

Tags: python

I am a beginner in Python trying to solve an exercise regarding image manipulation. The exercise says: Write a function that takes a picture as a list of lists of tuples (each tuple has three values representing an RGB color) and modifies it drawing all the squares present in the list in the given order.

Each element of the list is a tuble consists of the following elements:

```
(x,y,side,(color))
```

x, y = the position of the square to be drawn in the picture
l = the length in pixels of the square to be drawn
color = the RGB color described as a tuple of three values indicating the color of the square to be drawn

I know how to draw a single square on a picture. The problem is i don't know how i could draw multiple squares using a single function without calling it more than once.

```
import immagini


def disegna_quadrato (imm,x,y,l,colore):
    
    h,w = len(imm),len(imm[0])
    for i in range(y,y+l):
        for j in range(x,x+l):
            if i<h and j< w:
                imm[i][j]=colore            
                
def disegna_quadrati(imm,lista):
    
    for a in lista:
        for b in a:
            imm[a][b] = disegna_quadrato()
                
if __name__== '__main__':

 imm = immagini.load('fiore.png')
 im1 = disegna_quadrati (imm,[(20,20,40,(255,255,255)), (30,30,30,(180,180,180)), (40,40,20,(100,100,100))])
 immagini.save(imm,'fiore-squares.png')
```

As you can see in my code, the first function disegna_quadrato takes a picture, a few values and draws a single square. I want to draw the squares that are present in the list simply by calling the disegna_quadrati function once.

I don't know if using two functions is a good idea.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Using two functions is a good idea!

Keep going with your idea a send parameters to the first function when you're calling it in the second one.

Here of you can do that:

```
def disegna_quadrati(imm,lista): 
    for a in lista:
        disegna_quadrato(imm, a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3])
```

You do not need to loop over `a`, all the information is used once, all together.

Maybe I did not well understand your problem. Tell me if so.

If you have any questions, feel free to ask.